# Laravel 5.1 in_array not working correctly?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying too check if a specific array contains a specific value with the in_array method. But for some reason it seems like it's not working.

```
@if (in_array(Auth::id(), $likedUsers))
        <p>yes</p>
@endif
    <?php echo Auth::id() ?>
    <?php dd($likedUsers) ?>
```

The results of my 2 dumps:

[image: The results]

As you can see the array contains the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not how [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) works. Your array contains objects and the objects are the things that contain the user id. `in_array()` will check the exact elements of the array it doesn't check the properties of the elements (the objects in this case).

It does something like this:

```php
$isLikedUser = false;

foreach ($likedUsers as $likedUser) {
    if ($likedUser == Auth::id()) {
        $isLikedUser = true;
    }
}
```

But you need this:

```php
$isLikedUser = false;

foreach ($likedUsers as $likedUser) {
    if ($likedUser->user_id == Auth::id()) {
        $isLikedUser = true;
    }
}
```

You should do this in your controller and then you can pass the result to your view like this:

```
$view = View::make('viewname')->with('isLikedUser', $isLikedUser);
```

Note that you don't have to give the same name to your view variable when you use the `with()` function, like: `->with('variableNameInView', $usedVariableValue);`

Then your view will have a variable with the name of the first parameter that you can check:

```
@if ($isLikedUser)
    <p>yes</p>
@endif
<?php echo Auth::id() ?>
<?php dd($likedUsers) ?>
```

Comment: Oh I did not know this. Can I check the objects individualy with somehting like this $likedUsers->user_id?

Comment: Okay I see, but I do this foreach in my controller how do I pass the true/false value over to my view?

Comment: This also still gives me false as output unfortunately

Comment: I'm sorry, it's probably a stupid questions but how do I save the result to a variable? @totymedli

Comment: @MoussaChaabar Did you passed the variable to your view as I wrote it: `->with('isLikedUser', $isLikedUser);`?